# django-admin.py dumpdata to SQL statements

Tags: sql, django, django-admin, dumpdata

I'm trying to dump my data to SQL statements.
the django-admin.py dumpdata provides only json,xml,yaml.
so:

1. does someone know a good way to do it?!
2. I tried that:

   def sqldumper(model):

   ```
   result = ""
   units = model.objects.all().values()
   for unit in units:
       statement = "INSERT INTO myapp.model "+str(tuple(unit.keys())).replace("'", "")+" VALUES " + str(tuple(unit.values()))+"\r\n"
       result+=statement
   return result
   ```

so I'm going over the model values myself, and make the INSERT statement myself.
then I thought of using "django-admin.py sql" to get the "CREATE" statement.. but then I don't know how to use this line from inside my code (and not through the command-line).
I tried os.popen and os.system, but it doesn't really work..
any tips about that?

I'll put it clearly:
how do you use the "manage.py sql " from inside your code?

I add something like this to my view:

```
import os, sys
import imp
from django.core.management import execute_manager

sys_argv_backup = sys.argv
imp.find_module("settings")
import settings
sys.argv = ['','sql','myapp']
execute_manager(settings)
sys.argv = sys_argv_backup
```

the thing is - it works.. but it writes the statements to the stdout...
it's something, but not perfect. I'll try using django.core.management.sql.sql_create directly, we'll see how it goes..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use SQL-specific dump program (e.g. [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for MySQL).

For sqlite embedded in Python, you can look [this example](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump) not involving Django:

```
# Convert file existing_db.db to SQL dump file dump.sql
import sqlite3, os

con = sqlite3.connect('existing_db.db')
with open('dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for line in con.iterdump():
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Comment: I thought about it, but let's say I'm using the ordinary sqlite3 that you get from django. I know it's easy on MySQL, but how do you do it on sqlite?

Comment: I added some "steps" I made to the question above, it's not perfect, but it's something to make me closer to the goal.. thanks though Don