# Django sqlite3 database dump

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

How can i create Django sqlite3 dump file (*.sql) using terminal?

There is a fabric `fabfile.py` with certain dump scripts, but when i try to use `fab` command next massage shows up:

`The program 'fab' is currently not installed.  To run fab please ask your administrator to install the package 'fabric'`.

But there **are** fabric files in `/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/`.

I'm not good at Django and Python at all. The guy, who was responsible for our Django project, just left without any explanations.

In general i need to know how to create Django sqlite3 dump file (*.sql) via terminal.
Help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fab` is command included in `fabric` package. Having a `fabfile.py` does not mean you installed `fabric`. The `fabfile.py` is used by `fab`.

Install [`fabric`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric):

```
pip install fabric
```

then, you can use `fab` command.

Comment: But there are fabric files in `/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/`.

Comment: @Toon, Is there `fab` program? Is there is, try to specify the full path of the `fab`.

Comment: There are only *.py and *.pyc files

Comment: @Toon, If you properly installed `fabric`, there should be a `fab` command. Check the output of `pip freeze | grep -i fabric`

Comment: @Toon, `pip show -f fabric | grep fab$` will show you path of the `fab` program. If it's installed.

Comment: I guess fabric is not installed. Is there any way to make dump without it?

Comment: @Toon, Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881194/django-admin-py-dumpdata-to-sql-statements

Comment: I've found fab program in /bin/ folder, but still it's not working. I guess other methods are too difficult for me. So i'm going to get some paid help.

Comment: @Toon, What happen if you run `/bin/fab` in the directory where the `fabfile.py` is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use fixtures. And generate fixtures for your app. Dependes on what you're planing to do with them.

You'll just make a loaddata after that.